# Trying to POST to database with Simple Form and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form

Trying to use the simple-form gem with Rails to POST to my database (postgresql). I have followed a few videos but I'm not entirely sure what's going wrong. My form worked before I made the method to post (obviously didn't do anything).

Here's the error I get.

[image]

Straight away I was thinking a routes issue. But I've had a crack for a while and can't fix it.

```markdown
undefined method `client_assets_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000000ccd8>
Did you mean?  clients_new_path
```

Here's my [repo](https://github.com/benaitcheson/T2A2_Marketplace_App) if it helps with the models.

Here's my form:

```rb
<%= simple_form_for @clients do |f| %>
        <div class="form-inputs">
            <%# Home %>
            <%= f.input :ppor %>
            <br>
        </div>

        <div class="form-actions">
            <%= f.button :submit %>
        </div>
    <% end %
```

Here's my method in Client Controller:

```rb
class ClientController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @clients = ClientAsset.all
  end

  def new
    @clients = ClientAsset.new
  end

  def create
    @clients = ClientAsset.new(client_asset_params)
    if @clients.save
      redirect_to @clients
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def client_asset_params
    params.require(:id).permit(:ppor)
  end
end
```

and here's my routes:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :admins
  root to: "planner#index"

  get "/index", to: "planner#index", as: :index

  get "/howto", to: "planner#howto", as: :howto

  get "/products", to: "planner#products", as: :products

  get "/planners", to: "planner#planners", as: :planners

  get "/admins/sign_in", to: "admin#sign_in", as: :sign_in

  get "/admins/sign_up", to: "admin#sign_up", as: :sign_up

  devise_scope :admin do
    get "/admins/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  end

  get "/admins/password/edit", to: "devise/password#edit", as: :edit

  get "/dashboard", to: "client#dashboard", as: :dashboard

  get "clients/new", to: "client#new"

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instinct that you have a routing issue is correct.

The standard/default behaviour on a form like yours is to POST to the specified resource's 'index path' (`/clients` in your case). However, you have not defined a POST route.

The reason you get an undefined method error instead of a 'no route for' error is that `simple_form_for` assumes that your route has a 'named path helper' of the form '*class_name*_path' that will give it the appropriate destination URI. Since you don't have a route defined, `simple_form` doesn't find the associated method and you get a missing method error.

So, at a minimum you would need:

```rb
get "/clients/new", to: "client#new"
post "/clients", to: "client#create", as: 'client_assets'
```

The `as:` option is necessary because by default Rails creates the helper using the resource path name (`clients`) but `simple_form_for` assumes the that resource path is derived from the model name (`client_assets`).

As an aside, Rails works best and easiest when you stick to convention. If you are new to Rails, using things such as [resourceful routing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) and naming conventions for models and controllers (e.g., `ClientAsset` (model) `ClientAssetsController` (controller)) can make your experience with Rails quite a bit smoother.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things going on that are probably causing issues.  You're missing a route to your create method in your controller.  The HTTP verb should be POST. But this will probably not fix your problem. I will try and help point you in the right direction.

There is something I noticed in your routes file and I want to try and help steer you onto the restful path.  Most rails developers will shy away from creating routes like:

`get "clients/new", to: "client#new"`

Rails is amazing and handles this for you.  I would remove this and add this to your routes file:

`resource :clients`

This will automagically provide all the needed routes.  Index, show, new, create and destroy.

Once you add that to your routes file, run this in your shell (from the project directory) `rails routes`

You should notice you have all the routes I mentioned before.

Second thing I wanted to point out is your controller.  The class name for controllers are pluralized.  Model names are singular.

`class ClientController < ApplicationController`

a normal rails convention would be:

`class ClientsController < ApplicationController`

The third thing I would like to point out is this:

```
def new
  @clients = ClientAsset.new
end
```

Looking at your repo I can tell you this isn't right.  You shouldn't be instantiating a `ClientAsset` instance in a `Client` controller.

In a Client Controller, I would expect to see something like:

```
def new
  @client = Client.new
end
```

Using `@client` as you have in your form would never work, it will be looking for a completely different route and controller.

TBH, this is a lot to take in.  If you want, I can send up a PR in your repo to help get you back on track if you are interested.